# flashdevelop for game development

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flashdevelop, flex4.6

I'm trying out flashdevelop for flash game programming. I've searched around and any good resource tells me the flash IDE way of doing things. searching again, i come across flex, mxml, flex sdk. I feel like punching someone now.(lol. i'm joking).

Opening a new project on flashdevelop, i'm presented with the likes of "AS3 Project", "flex 4 Project"( which uses mxml and flex 4). what's the significant of mxml? and flex? where will AS3 poject take me?

can any stackoverflower direct me to a nice resource that shows the workflow of working on flashdevelop to create a simple flash game?

Comment: [This seems like a pretty good tutorial](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/beginners-guide-to-flashdevelop-intro-basix/):

Answer (score 3):

Things to know before you start

1. Tools like FlashDevelop DOESN"T have User Interface builder like the one you see in Flash Professional. Time-line is also not available. It is more like a source compiler.
2. The Library which you see in Flash Professional, in which you add MovieClips, Sprites which are retrieved at runtime is NOT available in any other alternatives.
3. You CAN store your basic resource files in a folder and Embed them in your swf using Actionscript. ref: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ff2.html
4. These resource files will be added to SWF when you compile it.
5. Using FlashDevelop you can Emebed and Load MovieClips created in Flash Professional and exported to an SWF file.

You will get help from sites like

- http://flashpunk.net/2011/05/setting-up-flashdevelop/
- http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/beginners-guide-to-flashdevelop-intro-basix/

Answer (score 1):

The Flex framework, which leverages MXML as a declarative markup language (XML to describe UIs), is Adobe's UI framework to develop applications. You probably don't need that ;)

Also do not confuse it with Adobe Flex SDK which is the command line compiler for both pure AS3 and MXML (FlashDevelop will have downloaded it for you).

You want to use an AS3 Project, or better, an AS3 Project with Preloader which will eventually be handy if you want to package your game as a single with a nice loading animation on start.

These template projects will just configure what is needed to start a pure AS3 app or game from scratch. As it's pure AS3 you start with the rather low-level AS3 API which requires quite a bit of learning to get anything moving on screen.

If you want to go into 2D games I recommend you read this great tutorial on how to use a nice Flash game library which will take care of most of the details:
http://www.photonstorm.com/archives/1200/flash-game-dev-tip-6-setting-up-flashdevelop-and-flixel-for-the-first-time